# C++, learning linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm learning a very simple linked list,
but this code below doesn't work, when I input 1 and 2, the system output is only 1 and NULL.
Could somebody help me please ?
This is my code.

```
#include <iostream>  

using namespace std;  

struct node  
{  
    char username[10];  

    node *next;  
};  



int main()  
{  
    node *head;  
    node *place;  
    node *tail;  

    head = new node;  
    place = head;  
    tail = place->next;  

    cout<<"username 1 ";  
    cin>>place->username;  
    place = tail;  
    place = new node;  
    tail = place->next;  
    cout<<"username 2 ";  
    cin>>place->username;  

    place = head;  
    cout<<"username 1 ";  
    cout<<place->username<<endl;  
    place = place->next;  
    cout<<"username 2 ";  
    cout<<place->username<<endl;  


    return 17;  
}
```

Any help from you will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The only way to learn how to program is to see what you're doing (and most importantly what you're doing wrong.) Set a breakpoint in the first line of your `main()` function and step through it line by line in a debugger. Check the value of each variable and see if it's what you expect.

Comment: Yeah I tried it, and my problem is actually I don't know how to link them. But now I do and thank you for spending your time with my question.

Answer (score 1):

You never link the nodes together.
Nowhere in this entire program do you set the *next* field.
Work this out on paper, one statement at a time.
Instead of ...

```
place = new node;  
tail = place->next;
```

When you create a new node, add it to the end of the list: link the current end to the new node, and then move the end pointer.

```
place = new node;  
tail->next = place;
tail = place;
```

Comment: It gave an error because you overwrite the address next to the _tail_ with the address of _tail_ itself, which is _place_ is the address of _tail_ at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>  

using namespace std;  

struct node  
{  
    char username[10];  

    node *next;  
};  



int main()  
{  
    node *head;  
    node *place;  
    node *tail; 

    place = new node;  
    head = place;      // head is assigned to the first created place and should never be modified ever after.
    tail = head;      // at the beginning the last element is also the first, it will move along and always point to the last node created



    cout<<"username 1 ";  
    cin>>place->username;


    place = new node;    // create new node
    tail->next = place;  // assign next
    tail = place;        // then point the tail to the new node

    cout<<"username 2 ";  
    cin>>place->username;  

    place = head;      // rewind the list to the head
    cout<<"username 1 ";  
    cout<<place->username<<endl;  
    place = place->next;  
    cout<<"username 2 ";  
    cout<<place->username<<endl;  


    return 17;  
}
```

Comment: This works, now I understand, so we make a new node and place the node next to the address of the head. Instead of we make a new address and make a new node in the new address. Well at least now I understand, thank you so much.

Comment: Almost. Actually the head is a pointer and has no address at the beginning.  When you create a new node, this node has an address. Then you assign that node's address to the head. Then head has an address but has no "next". When you create another object, you assign its address to the next, and so on.